# How can I fix 'No space left on device' error in Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm running a Mac-native Docker (no virtualbox/docker-machine).

I have a huge image with a lot of infrastructure in it (Postgres, etc.).
I have run cleanup scripts to get rid of a lot of cruft--unused images and so forth.

When I run my image I get an error like:

```
could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": No space left on device
```

On my host Mac /var is sitting at 60% space available and generally my disk has lots of storage free.

Is this some Docker configuration I need to bump up to give it more resources?

Relevant lines from `mount` inside docker:

```
none on / type aufs (rw,relatime,si=5b19fc7476f7db86,dio,dirperm1)
/dev/vda1 on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/resolv.conf type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/hostname type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/hosts type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda1 on /var/lib/postgresql/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Here’s `df`:

```
[11:14]  
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
none           202054928 4333016 187269304   3% /
tmpfs            1022788       0   1022788   0% /dev
tmpfs            1022788       0   1022788   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1      202054928 4333016 187269304   3% /data
shm                65536       4     65532   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             204560     284    204276   1% /run/docker.sock
```

Comment: What do you see if you run `mount` and `df` as root inside the Docker instance? (add it to the question)  -- also give us the relevant parts of `docker inspect` output for the running container.

Comment: OK, so the interesting part is that you've got `/dev/vda1` mounted as `/var/lib/postgresql/data`  (as well as `/data` <shrug>). But it has exactly the same free space as `/` so is probably the same volume under the covers, and it's nowhere near full at the moment you ran `df`. I defer to the Docker gods. `docker inspect` will probably reveal more.

Comment: By default, containers get a 10GB space, that is probably the wall you are running into. I don't have time at the moment to look much further, but I believe you can increase it, and take a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/

Answer (score 40):

I haven't found many options for this, the main issue in github is https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371

Some of the options suggested there are:

- If you can remove all images/containers, you can follow these instructions:

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls |awk '{print $2}')
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/*`

- You can try to prune all unused images/containers but this has proven not very effective:

`docker system prune`

- Use a template image that is larger, install `qemu` using homebrew and move the image around, see this specific comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371#issuecomment-242047368 but you need to have at least 2x of space left to do this without losing containers/images.

See also: [How do you get around the size limitation of Docker.qcow2 in the Docker for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402363/how-do-you-get-around-the-size-limitation-of-docker-qcow2-in-the-docker-for-mac)
And https://forums.docker.com/t/no-space-left-on-device-error/10894/26

Answer (score 35):

I ran into the same issue, running `docker system prune --volumes` resolved the problem.

"Volumes are not pruned by default, and you must specify the --volumes flag for docker system prune to prune volumes."

See: https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-everything

Comment: I needed to run an extra `docker system prune` without `--volumes` after this.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this recently on with a docker installation on linux that uses the `devicemapper` storage driver (default). There was indeed a docker configuration I needed to change to fix this.

Docker images are made of read-only layers of filesystem snapshots, each layer created by a command in your `Dockerfile`, which are built on top of a common base storage snapshot. The base snapshot is shared by all your images and has a file system with a default size of 10GB. When you run your image you get a new writable layer on top of all the layers in the image, so you can add new files in your running container but it's still eventually based on the same base snapshot with the 10GB filesystem. This is at least true for `devicemapper`, not sure about other drivers. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) is the relevant documentation from docker.

To change this default value to something else, there's a daemon parameter you can set, e.g. `docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G`. Since you probably don't run the daemon manually need to edit the docker daemon options in some file, depending on how you run the docker daemon. With docker for mac you can edit the daemon parameters as JSON in the preferences under `Daemon->Advanced`. You probably need to add something like this:

```
{
    "storage-opts": ["dm.basesize=100G"]
}
```

(but like I said, I had this problem on linux, so didn't try the above).

Anyway in order for this to take effect, you'll need to remove all your existing images (so that they're re-created on top of the new base snapshot with the new size). See [storage driver options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#storage-driver-options).

Comment: Note that this is only for devicemapper and OSX doesn't use that: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2134

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I had this situation while using `docker load` to import a large image, but I had at least 4 times as much storage on the destination device. For completeness, [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) are the docker docs for the location of the JSON configuration file on linux (generally `/etc/docker/daemon.json`). Do not forget to restart the docker daemon after changing the file (e.g. `sudo service docker restart`).

Comment: This will brick Docker on a Mac M1.

Answer (score 1):

This issue also happened to me.

For me, the fix was to increase the 'Virtual Disk Limit' size in Docker Desktop (Mac).

[image: Virtual Disk Limit setting]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prune everything use `docker image prune -a`