# Expanding HDFS memory in Cloudera QuickStart on docker

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs, cloudera

I try to use the Cloudera QuickStart Docker Image, but it seems that there is no free space on hdfs (0 Bytes).

After starting the Container

```
 docker run --hostname=$HOSTNAME -p 80:80 -p 7180:7180 -p 8032:8032 -p      8030:8030 -p 8888:8888 -p 8983:8983 -p 50070:50070 -p 50090:50090 -p 50075:50075 -p 50030:50030 -p 50060:50060 -p 60010:60010 -p 60030:60030 -p 9095:9095 -p 8020:8020 -p 8088:8088 -p 4040:4040 -p 18088:18088 -p 10020:10020 --privileged=true -t -i cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

I can start the Cloudera Manager

```
$/home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --express
```

and to log into the web gui.
Here I can see that dfs.datanode.data.dir is the default /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data

On the console my hdfs dfsadmin -report gives me:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report 
Safe mode is ON
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
```

But when I look at the the container

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          63G  8.3G   52G  14% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        63G  8.3G   52G  14% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/sda1        63G  8.3G   52G  14% /etc/hostname
/dev/sda1        63G  8.3G   52G  14% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
cm_processes    5.9G  7.8M  5.9G   1% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

What I have to do to add additional space to hfs?

Answer (score 0):

> Here I can see that dfs.datanode.data.dir is the default /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data

You can use a volume mount into that directory.

More importantly, running `df` within a container is misleading, and on Mac or Windows, the Docker qcow2 file is only a limited size to begin with.

[How do you get around the size limitation of Docker.qcow2 in the Docker for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402363/how-do-you-get-around-the-size-limitation-of-docker-qcow2-in-the-docker-for-mac)

It looks like you have no datanodes running